# PDF File Popup while opening in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, windows-10

I am facing a problem while opening a PDF file in internet explorer 11 in windows 10. When I search in document and Adobe completes search, it gives a message the reader has completed search. Now problem is that this pop up box comes at the Top Left upper corner and not in the middle of the internet explorer. If I open in Adobe PDF then pop up comes in middle of PDF. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why is this a problem?
Are you performing some kind of automated testing, where you expect the screen to always look the same pixel-perfect?

Comment: I am not performing any kind of automated testing but it is kind of obstacle while searching and entering data from PDF to excel. Because I need to click on OK button through mouse all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should automate this? I can imagine it must be very boring to just copy/paste data from a pdf to an excel document.

Consider using pdf2Data. It's an iText7 add-on that is capable of turning a structured pdf (tables, lists, text at certain positions, etc) into an XML file. And XML can be imported into Excel.

For more information, look at the example video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8nfRLG6NjU&t=12s